# Trouble with basic add/sub/mul/div program in C?

Tags: c, runtime-error

I am trying to write a simple program that inputs two floats and an operation sign and, using the ASCII value of the operation sign, branches to a specific line and outputs the correct answer. However, the program does not allow me to enter the third input, the operation sign, and so the only output I get is 0. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
double x, y, answer;
char operation;


//enter the two operands which are held in x and y, respectively
scanf("%f %f", &x, &y);


//enter operation to be performed, ASCII value of operation (42 is *, 43 is 
//+, 45 is -, 47 is /) is stored in "operation" identifier
op:                    //label "op," not sure if I used this correctly
scanf("%c", &operation);


//if "+" was entered add x and y
if(operation=43){
    answer = x + y;
    printf("%.3f", answer);
}

//if "-" was entered subtract y from x
else if(operation=45){
    answer = x - y;
    printf("%.3f", answer);
}

//if "/" was entered divide x by y
else if(operation=47){
    answer = x / y;
    printf("%.3f", answer);
}

//if "*" was entered multiply x by y
else if(operation=42){
    answer = x * y;
    printf("%.3f", answer);
}

//if no valid operation entered rescan for valid operation
else goto op;

    return 0;
}
```

And here is what is shown on the console:

```
1
1
0.000
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 4.694 s
Press any key to continue.
```

As seen above, I am unable to indicate the operation I wish to perform. I'm sure it's a simple mistake. Are there any blatantly obvious errors that could be pointed out to me so that, hopefully, this program will run correctly?

Comment: Do not use `goto` - Use a `do ... while loop` Also learn to use the deb ugger

Comment: Perhaps a switch statement would be better than those if statements

Comment: Did you not get warnings for all the '=' instead of '=='?

Answer (score 3):

`scanf("%c", &operation);` would be

`scanf(" %c", &operation);`

That will make sure that we don't consume the `\n` character from previous input. 
In your case that is exactly the case, your `operation` variable holds the value charcater `\n`. The `' '` in `scanf` enusres that all the white space charcaters are consumed. And then you get the correct char input.

And also `operation = 45` would be `operation == 45`. Even more simply you can do this

```
if( operation == '+')
```

Earlier you were using the assignment. You were not checking equality. `==`.

Also here you have used `goto` which can be easily converted to a while statement. Here you don't need `goto` - goto creates an control flow which is much harder to debug. You can do it simply like this here.

```
do{
...



}while(operation!='+' || operation!='-'..);
```

or with

```
   while(1){
   ...
    if( operation == '+' || operation == '-' ..)
        break;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the equality operator in the `if` statements. Also instead of thos "magic" numbers - use the character

i.e.

```
 if (operation=='+') { ....
```